# JWT token from social sign up at ngnix plus gateway

Tags: java, rest, jwt

We are using NGNIX Plus for JWT token authorization , so whenever sign in happens our api will provide one token to the calling client which gets verified at the ngnix layer.
But question is , how to verify the token we will get from signin in from Google / Facebook ?  How will our ngnix plus can validate those ?
How can we make ngnix plus to verify those JWT token.

Comment: What I make, user sign in with Google/Facebook. You get the oauth or validation token, you verify the social network token against their api, if ok you can use that info to get your own user data or add the social network data to your JWT token.

Comment: We have a in house sign in also how to handle that ? How the NGNIX + gateway authorize the Google / Facebook token ..

Comment: I don't know about your NGINX implementation problem, but I did something similar, where users log in with Google account. My systems verify login attempts, if ok then search my user data in DB and generate my JWT custom token. You can create users in your system silently to authenticate social medias.